# Physical vapor deposition of $\rm SiO_2$

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technique

Could you suggest any if it's possible to deposit a layer of $\rm SiO_2$ via PVD?

Why doesn't it widely used? Is that correct that I need $~1600\ C$ in vacuum?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by PVD? There are many techniques for producing thin film coatings, and a number of them could be called "Physical Vapor Deposition."  I'm wondering whether you are referring to a specific type of process, or just to vapor deposition in general.

Comment: Well, in general. Mainly, Evaporative deposition(for example, on tungsten heater), then sputter deposition.

Comment: The wikipedia page for CVD has a whole section on depositing SiO2. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_vapor_deposition#Silicon_dioxide) I don't see any reason to believe that it's not possible or that it isn't widely used.

Comment: If the substrate is Silicon it is simply grown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deposit $SiO_2$ with PVD, ion plating.

The lower the pressure the lower the evaporation temperature needed.

The question is what do you want to deposit the $SiO_2$ onto and how thick?

You can use an RF plasma ($13.56 \  \mathrm{MHz}$ at about $5-15 \  W /m^3$, $Ar$ gas) with $DC$ bias on the part.
Use powdered $SiO_2$ in a tunsten or Ta boat with negative melting current.
Shoot at about $5 × 10-4 \ \mathrm{millliTorr}$.

Bias the part, on an isolated steel or copper tray, with $30-40V$ $DC$ $+$ at up to $7 \ amps$.

The other side of the $DC$ circuit is the grounded vacuum chamber wall.
You must ground everything to the chamber and then ground the chamber.

Look at [www.lesker.com](http://www.lesker.com) or svc.org for details on setup.
Or you could send it to me or any number of coaters and they can coat it for you.
Look up vacuum coating PVD.

Comment: Thanks for the details - I was thinking about depositing SiO2 as gate dielectric in ASICs, but now I realize that I would not get required interface quality compared to thermal oxide...

Answer (score 3):

$\mathrm{SiO_2}$ is very commonly used in optical coatings. A typical example is the production of [Dielectric Mirrors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_mirror) which works just like a silver or aluminum mirror, but can achieve very high reflectivity, upwards of $99.9\%$, and can be made to work only at very specific wavelengths.

In this application $SiO_2$ (called silica, generally) is often used in combination with $HaO_2$ (hafnium oxide, or hafnia).Alternating layers are deposited on a glass substrate in very specific thicknesses to produce the desired optical qualities.

I'm not really an expert on optical coatings, but I work closely with people who are, and I don't believe that the temperature needs to be quite as high as $1600C$ . For typical processes, temperatures are in the range of $900C$  for the silica source, but much lower for the substrate being coated. More recently, I've heard that we are using some sort of plasma assisted coating technique, which I gather can operate at much lower temperatures, $400C$ or below. This is because the energetic ions in the plasma knock silica off of the source without much heating, and apparently produces higher quality coatings as well.

EDIT: As Georg pointed out, the material being removed from the coating source is not molecular silica, but some other combination of silicon/oxygen compounds. I assume that an $SiO_2$ crystal structure re-forms on the coated optic, but I do not really know for sure.

The wikipedia page on [Silicon Dioxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_dioxide) is quite thorough, and has good references which should give you a good starting point if you want to do more research. I also found this [list of books](http://www.svc.org/Publications/Books-of-Interest-to-Vacuum-Coaters.cfm), and this [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=Qi98H-iTgLEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false) as well, although I cannot personally tell you if they are good books or not.

Comment: Could you please ask for temperature and books they would recommend? :-)

Comment: @BarsMonster: I edited the answer, but keep in mind this is second hand information. If you're going to do any serious work you should talk to an expert.